# React Navigation + react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to create an app that has a bottom navigation tab with the four screen tab menu. I want to have another page for Admin but the menu option should not appear on the bottom tab. ( I have a  to go to that page) I am using [react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/material-bottom-tab-navigator.html) to create the bottom tab bar.

I need a way to go to that page.

```
export default createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(

  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Home",
        tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Home</Text>,
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#281b39" },
        tabBarIcon: <Icon size={24} name="home" style={{ color: "white" }} />
      }
    },
    Announcement: {
      screen: AnnouncementScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Announcement",
        tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Announcements</Text>,
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#0e141d" },
        tabBarIcon: (
          <Icon size={24} name="bullhorn" style={{ color: "white" }} />
        )
      }
    },
    Material: {
      screen: MaterialScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Materials",
        tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Materials</Text>,
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#E64A19" },
        tabBarIcon: (
          <Icon size={24} name="calendar" style={{ color: "white" }} />
        )
      }
    },
    Contact: {
      screen: ContactScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Contact",
        tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Contact</Text>,
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#524365" },
        tabBarIcon: (
          <Icon size={24} name="comments" style={{ color: "white" }} />
        )
      }
    },   },

  {
    shifting: true,
    labeled: true   } );
```

Here is an updated version

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AppRegistry, Text, View, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";

import Home from "./app/components/home.js";
import Announcements from "./app/components/announcements.js";
import Contact from "./app/components/contact.js";

import BackgroundImage from "./app/components/BackgroundImage.js";

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BackgroundImage>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
        <Home />
      </BackgroundImage>
    );
  }
}

class AnnouncementScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Announcements>
        <StatusBar hidden={true} />
      </Announcements>
    );
  }
}

class MaterialScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", top: 200 }}>
          This is going to be the Materials Screen
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class ContactScreen extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Contact />;
  }
}

class AdminPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return <Text>Hi</Text>;
  }
}

const Admins = {
  Admin: {
    screen: AdminPage
  }
};

const ContactStack = createStackNavigator({
  Contact: {
    screen: ContactScreen
  },
  ...Admins
});

const AppNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Home",
        tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Home</Text>,
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#281b39" },
        tabBarIcon: <Icon size={24} name="home" style={{ color: "white" }} />
      }
    },
    Announcement: {
      screen: AnnouncementScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Announcement",
        tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Announcements</Text>,
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#0e141d" },
        tabBarIcon: (
          <Icon size={24} name="bullhorn" style={{ color: "white" }} />
        )
      }
    },
    Material: {
      screen: MaterialScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Materials",
        tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Materials</Text>,
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#E64A19" },
        tabBarIcon: (
          <Icon size={24} name="calendar" style={{ color: "white" }} />
        )
      }
    },
    Contact: {
      screen: ContactStack,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: "Contact",
        tabBarLabel: <Text style={{ color: "white" }}>Contact</Text>,
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#524365" },
        tabBarIcon: (
          <Icon size={24} name="comments" style={{ color: "white" }} />
        )
      }
    }
  },

  {
    shifting: true,
    labeled: true
  }
);

const App = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

export default App;
```

Comment: What is menu option?

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of a `StackNavigator` to go to a new screen.

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs";

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Admin")}>Home</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Announcement extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Admin")}>Announcement</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Material extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Material</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Contact extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Contact</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Admin extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Admin</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const commonScreens = {
  Admin: {
    screen: Admin
  }
};

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home
  },
  ...commonScreens
});

const AnnouncementStack = createStackNavigator({
  Announcement: {
    screen: Announcement
  },
  ...commonScreens
});

const AppNavigator = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: HomeStack },
    Announcement: { screen: AnnouncementStack },
    Material: { screen: Material },
    Contact: { screen: Contact }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Home",
    activeColor: "#f0edf6",
    barStyle: { backgroundColor: "#694fad" },
    labeled: true
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

[image: nav]

There are options for removing the header as well. 
For more information please have a look at the docs https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#stacknavigatorconfig

Comment: Is there a way to change it to the admin page when I press a button instead of clicking the screen?

Comment: I keep getting a `(0 , -reactNavigation.createAppContainer) is not a function`

Comment: I have the import and I got the modules

Comment: I am not sure what exactly your are doing, maybe you can add some code to your question to help me in understanding the error you are seeing.

Comment: Which version of `react-navigation` are you using?

Comment: "react-navigation": "^2.18.3",

Comment: You must have the latest version `3.3.2` for `createAppContainer ` to work.

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay but I was having a lot of errors but I came here

`Error: This navigator has both navigation and container props, so it is unclear if it should own its own state. Remove props: "rootTag" if the navigator should get its state from the navigation prop. If the navigator should maintain its own state, do not pass a navigation prop.`

Comment: Could you please help on question related to bottom tabs? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61940177/react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs-set-initialroutename-dynamically